# How to improve performance of reading a text file of integers separated by spaces in Java?

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader

I have a software that read text files where each line is a list of integers separated by spaces.

I wrote the following code for reading the file, which works fine.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    String line;
    // for each lineuntil the end of file
    while( ((line = reader.readLine())!= null)){ 
        // if the line is  a comment or is empty
        if (line.isEmpty() == true ||  line.charAt(0) == '#') {
            continue;
        }

        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        for(String token: tokens ){  
            // read the value
            Integer value = Integer.parseInt(token);

            // .... do something

        }
    }
```

However, I would like to increase the performance. In particular, I think that using split() may not be the best way to do in terms of performance. My question is: how to improve the performance of this method?   By the way, note that I'm aware that disk accesses may be more costly than what is done in this method. But I'm still looking to see if I can optimize that method.

Comment: I think what you have is fine. Don't go for micro optimization. Keep your code readable & maintainable. Only suggestion is put Integer value = Integer.parseInt(token); in a try catch so that you do stop is there is a bad value.

Comment: why and what kind of optimization? Where do you think your program fails to perform?

Comment: @SMA  I was thinking that the split() may not be the best way to do because it requires to create Strings which are then put into an array, which may not be necessary. Another way could be to read character by character and convert to int when a space is encountered rather than after a split.  Beside, I'm good at Java. But I'm not an expert. If there is any other idea for improvements such as using something else instead of a bufferedreader or any other idea, I would be happy to hear about it. This is also why i'm asking this question.

Comment: @Phil then do for(String token: line.split(" ") ) { }

Comment: Although you say "I'm aware that disk accesses may be more costly than what is done in this method," I don't think you really believe it.  External I/O is *far* more costly than anything else that method does.  If it is not performing well enough for you, and the file you're reading is non-trivial in size, then you could try increasing the size of the `BufferedReader`'s buffer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Thanks. I had not thought about increasing the buffer size. I will try this idea.

Comment: The only low hanging fruit that I can see: avoid the autoboxing. parseInt() returns a primitive int; and unless you need an Integer object for further processing, the implicit object creation could be avoided. Besides that I agree to what have been said here: only optimize when real performance issues become visible. And then, your first step is not to look into code, but to profile the behavior of your application.

Comment: Ok thanks. That is also a good idea.